# Page footer iReport somente na primeira pagina

Tags: ireport, relatório

estou criando um relatório com o iReport porém não tenho muito conhecimento, então peço a ajuda de vocês.

Seguinte, preciso que o conteúdo de minha band page footer apareça somente na primeira página do relatório, até ai tudo bem, coloquei no Print When Expression ... $V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1 ? true : false.

Porem nas outras páginas ele não mostra o conteúdo mas continua ocupando o espaço, como removo esse espaço em branco nas páginas subsequentes?

Answer (score 1):

Você provavelmente está colocando a expressão no lugar errado, veja a imagem abaixo:

[image: Imagem Page Footer]

Na palheta "Report Inspector" (lado esquerdo), selecione a aba "Page Footer". Sua expressão deve fica nesta "Page Footer" e não em um elemento em específico.

O que provavelmente está acontecendo, é que ele está escondendo seu conteúdo mas mantem o espaço do "Page Footer" porque não há nenhuma expressão de condição lá.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, eu estava com este mesmo problema e acabei descobrindo que isso é uma limitação do iReport, mesmo que você esconda o conteudo colocando uma expressão no `Print When Expression` do `Page Footer` na hora da renderização o iReport reserva aquele espaço.

Como eu resolvi? Bem não sei se é a maneira correta, mas foi a melhor forma que encontrei. Vamos lá...

Para o meu `PageFooter` eu defini um tamanho de 1px, em seguida ao invés de colocar todo o conteúdo nessa band o que eu fiz foi criar um `subreport` contendo todo o conteúdo que eu queria que aparecesse somente na primeira página. Coloquei esse `subreport` no meu `PageFooter` também com o tamanho de 1px e pronto, funcionou como eu queria, porque? Simples, por padrão o `subreport` expande automaticamente seu tamanho de acordo com seu conteúdo o que o faz aparecer na primeira página, como nas outras ele não aparece e o tamanho que você definiu da band e do próprio `subreport` foi 1px isso ficará imperceptível ao usuário.

No meu caso funcionou perfeitamente, espero que funcione para você também.